# Join with condition with different column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following two tables :

**user_profile**

```
id | name  | email       | phone
1  | Rahul |r@gmail.com  |1234567890
2  | Rohan |r1@gmail.com |1234567890
3  | Mohan |m@gmail.com  |1234567890
```

**user_request_table**

```
    id | from_user_id|to_user_id|status
    1  |      1      |   2      | 2 
    2  |      3      |   1      | 2
```

Here status

> 0 = Request is cancel,
> 1 = request is pending,
> 2 = request accepted
> I have following section to display :

**Find a friend**

Here I need to display suggetion for friend. I need to display all record from user_profile table but user should not be a friend(status should not be 2) or request should not be pending(status should not be 1).

**So if I logged in as Rohan(id : 2) it should suggest me Mohan as friend suggestion.**

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
SELECT
 u.* 
FROM
 user_profile u
 LEFT JOIN user_request_table r ON u.id=r.to_user_id AND r.from_user_id = <your_logged_in_user_id>
WHERE
 r.status NOT IN (2,1) --filter pending and accepted here ;
```

Comment: This query is not return expected output
need to improve join
single join may not work, need multiple join or sub query

Comment: It is possible that my query does not work. I didn't test it on DB. But explain a bit how it does not return expected output.

Comment: Resultset would include logged user as well, so your comment on next answer is valid here.

Comment: u.id=r.to_user_id this will check all user in profile table but you have to check only logged in user, 
so in this case you should check either loggedin user in from or to both and also status in (1,2) and neglect them all

Comment: Note that there is an AND condition in join. So this query gets all lines from user profiles, joins them to requests made by user and right side of join is NULL if there isn't line matching logged user id in from_user_id column.

Answer (score 0):

So you want those records in `user_profile` table that do not have a record in `user_request` table where user is either `from_user_id` or `to_user_id`. The pattern is to do a left join to `user_request` and filter out those where `user_request.id` is null:

```
select
    p.*
from
    user_profile as p
    left join user_request as r on
        (
            (p.id = r.from_user_id and r.to_user_id = {id})
        or
            (p.id = r.to_user_id and r.from_user_id = {id})
        )
        and r.status in (1,2)
where
    r.id is null
    and p.id <> {id}
;
```

with `{id}` a parameter for the user you want to suggest friends for.

Comment: user should not be suggested itself 
you need to filter loggedin user as well

Comment: Yes you are right. I updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

First get all possible pairs from the user_profile table. Next filter through all the pairs and eliminate the unqualified using data from the user_request_table. It will get all the eligible (from_user , to_user)pairs.

```
select u1_id as fromuser,u2_id as touser
    from
        (select distinct u1.id as u1_id,u2.id as u2_id from user_profile u1 cross join user_profile u2 where u1.id!=u2.id) all_pair
    where not exists
        (select from_user_id ,to_user_id from user_request_table where status>0 and (
                ((u1_id=from_user_id) and(u2_id=to_user_id))  or   ((u1_id=to_user_id) and(u2_id=from_user_id))
            )
        )
;
```

The result set looks like this:
fromuser, touser
3 2
2 3

Comment: Well, this is probably the intended result so the logged-in user (as the from_user) can check whom ( as the to_user ) they could sent a request to. However, what if we want to eliminate the duplicate pair ( i.e  3 - 2 and 2 - 3 are counted as duplicate pair and only one pair is required ) .  Could someone please elaborate how to achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

This solution is for MSSQL SERVER, you can modify as per your preferred server

Pass your logged in id to declared variable

```
DECLARE @LoginId AS INT
SET @LoginId=2 /*here I passed logged in id as 2*/
SELECT  * FROM user_profile up 
WHERE 1=1 and id<>@LoginId
AND id NOT IN (SELECT from_user_id FROM user_request_table WHERE to_user_id=@LoginId and STATUS in(1,2)) 
AND id NOT IN (SELECT to_user_id FROM user_request_table WHERE from_user_id=@LoginId and STATUS in(1,2))
```

Comment: What is `WHERE 1=1` for? Looks useless for me.

Comment: its good practice to write like this for dynamic where clause, you no need to manage condition for multiple filter, here not needed but just part of habit : )